# multiple select with checkbox in php

Tags: php, ajax

i am making a website in which i am to embbed the functionality of delete using multiple checkbox. here is my code. my problem is 
1. Ajax call is not working.
2. how can i make search from database for array .

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['Delete']))
{
    $array=$_POST['check_box'];

    }
?>
<form method="post" id="form">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>NAme</td>
    <td>Action</td>
  </tr>

  <?php
  while($selectnumberarr=mysql_fetch_array($selectnumber))
  {
  ?>
  <tr>

    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_box[]" class="check_box" id="<?php $selectnumberarr[0]; ?>" /> </td>
    <td><?php echo $selectnumberarr[1]; ?></td>

  </tr>
  <?php
  }?>
  <input type="submit" name="Delete" id="delete">


</table>
</form>
```

and below is my ajax and javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#delete').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkbox.php",
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                alert("true");
            }
        });//end ajax
    });
}); 
 </script>
```

any help would be appriciated

Comment: Any error in the console.?

Comment: "how can i make search from database for array"- please explain

Comment: @rookieB: in above ajax code i am sending data in array now for delete  that data i have to search database according to that array. elements in array would got delete form database

Comment: @Deepu: no dear there is no error.

Comment: I have updatet my code, so you can take this one and replace yours with this. That should work. :)

Answer (score 2):

your code is almost correct. You need to remove `onChange="show()" for input checkbox, because if you have jquery then you don't need to put events on HTML elements.

Use jquery ['on'](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for compatibility for latest php library.

Replace your jquery code with following jquery code :-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#delete').on('click',function()
  {

       var cat_id = $('.check_box:checked').map(function() {
           return this.id;
         }).get().join(',');
                 console.log(cat_id);

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "checkbox.php",
          data: { "kw ":cat_id },
          datatype:'json',
          success: function(html)
          {
              alert("true");
          }
      });//end ajax

  });
});
</script>
```

Use ".check_box" instead of "element" in jquery to prevent checks for all checkboxes, instead of desired ones.

Hope it helps.

Comment: when i alert the cat_id than m getting ,,,(when i checked 4 checboxes ) in alert box.                                       i am using alert as below                                                         success: function(html)
          {
              alert(cat_id);
          }

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use an array for sending the checkboxes like:

HTML part:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['check_box'])) {
    var_dump($_POST['check_box']);
    echo "ajax call is working";
}
?>
<form id="form">
    <table width="200" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>select</td>
            <td>NAme</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>

        <?php
        while ($selectnumberarr = mysql_fetch_array($selectnumber)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_box[]" class="check_box" value="<?php echo $selectnumberarr[0]; ?>" /> </td>
                <td><?php echo $selectnumberarr[1]; ?></td>

            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <input type="button"name="delete" id="delete" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

JQuery part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#delete').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkbox.php",
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                alert("true");
            }
        });//end ajax
    });
}); 
</script>
```

So you can easily get an array of the selected checkboxes in php with:

```
$idsArray = $_POST["check_box"];
```

this looks now like:

```
array(
"1", "2","etc.."
);
```

so this array contains all the ids of the selected checkboxes for delete.

Comment: can  u please explain this

Comment: I have updatet my answer. Hope this is more clear what i mean. :)

Comment: Did you put the "form" tag outside of the "table" tag in your code and have you checked what data the ajax request sends to your "checkbox.php"?